# Spark Error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook'" even when jupyter is installed

Tags: python, linux, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run pyspark in the linux terminal. I have most of the installation done but I am getting the following error when I call `pyspark` in the linux terminal:

```
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook` in the future
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-110>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 307, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 455, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 302, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-4>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 514, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 244, in initialize_subcommand
    return super(BaseIPythonApplication, self).initialize_subcommand(subc, argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 445, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipython_genutils/importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook'
```

Most other forums say to install jupyter as follows:

```
pip install jupyter
```

but I already have this done.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython3 pyspark
```

Comment: @I_Am_Yohan Do you have installed ipython on your laptop?

Comment: Solved the problem. Turns out my Linux VM was calling Python2 using the command "Python" rather than Python3. Does anyone know how to fix this?